# string input with spaces using c++?

Tags: c++

I have tried all methods to get string input that have spaces in c++ ,
here is what i have tried so far

```
       string  CustomerinputNumber ;
    string CustomerName = "";       
     string CustomerAddress = "";
    string CustomerContactNo = "";
     ofstream myfile;
      myfile.open ("Customer.txt", std::ios_base::app);     
    cout << "Customer Identification Number : ";        
    cin>>CustomerinputNumber; 
    cout << "Customer Name : ";
     getline(cin, CustomerName);
    cout << "Customer Address : ";
        cin>> CustomerAddress;
       cout << "Customer Contact Number : ";
    cin>> CustomerContactNo;
```

and other methods

```
         std::string line;
         getline(cin, line);
```

but when I enter space it assign the value to next cin>>var variable so this question may be marked as duplicate but trust me I found no solution. So can any body tell me how to get string with spaces as input in c++ like

```
 Enter value: wasif albert green

 value is   : wasif albert green
```

Comment: The `std::getline` version should work fine. What went wrong when you tired it? (post ALL the relevant code to reproduce your problem)

Comment: [`std::noskipws`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws)

Comment: `operator>>` consumes leading whitespace unless you use `std::noskipws`.  `std::getline()` preserves whitespace.

Comment: I am pretty sure you are seeing the same problem as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction.

Comment: noskipws will include leading white space between strings, but it will still delimit a string on seeing white space

Comment: What happens, when you use `getline(cin, CustomerName)` instead of `cin >> CustomerName`?

Comment: it wont stay on screen

Comment: even not demand fopr input from user it pases